# Sending information via a lambda function and tkinter buttons results in TypeError [Python]

Tags: python, lambda, tkinter, typeerror

I'm having this problem where I first try to go to a def BP() from test2 which looks like this:

```
def Backpack():
print clr
act2.BP(player,mob,items)
```

This works just fine. Here's the tricky part though. you see def BP() looks like this:

```
def BP(p,m,it):
    print lb,"""Aah you wanna grab something out of your backpack?
go ahead then shitkid, that something ain't gonna pick up itself!""",lb
    time.sleep(2)
    print "You have",it[0],"swords and",it[1],"potions",lb
    time.sleep(2)
    print ("Watcha wanna pick up?")
    items = Tk()
    items.title("Backpack")
    items.geometry('350x100+520+320')

    def Sword(p,it):
        if it[0] >=1:
            p[1]+=3
            p[2]+=3
            it[0]-=1
            print lb, "Suh-weeeet! You got +3 strenght!",lb
            time.sleep(2)
        else:
            print "Silly shitkid, you don't have any swords!"
        items.destroy()

    def Potion(p,it):
        if it[1] >=1:
            p[0] += 10
            print ("Aaaaaw yiiis! Your HP is now", p[0])
        else:
        print "Silly shitkid, you don't have any potions!"
        items.destroy()

    s = Button(items, text="SWORD", command=lambda: Sword(p,it))
    p = Button(items, text="POTION", command=lambda: Potion(p,it))

    s.pack()
    p.pack()

    items.mainloop()
```

And what it's supposed to do is that if you have a sword or a potion it will take away 1 from the list that you chose. If you don't have a potion or a sword it will print out that you don't have any of those items and then go back to the first menu where you can chose to enter the backpack.

The thing is that def Sword() and def Potion() only works when you don't have any items. That is to say that it works when it is going through the "else". Otherwise I get an error that I can't understand which looks like this:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1410, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Sebastian\Desktop\Programmin\act2.py", line 112, in <lambda>
p = Button(items, text="POTION", command=lambda: Potion(p,it))
  File "C:\Users\Sebastian\Desktop\Programmin\act2.py", line 105, in Potion
p[0] += 10
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1206, in cget
return self.tk.call(self._w, 'cget', '-' + key)
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects
```

I was hoping that someone could help me understand this problem and help me with it.  I've posted a link where you can get the full code below. I'm greatful for any help that I can get!

http://www.files.com/set/54451a748f6a2

**EDIT:** I have figured out that when I try to send "p" and "it" into "Sword" p changes into 3
.45644104L Why is this?

Comment: the indentation of your code is incorrect.

Comment: Can you please specify where and why it matters?

Comment: `print clr` is immediately below `def Backpack()`. A similar problem after `def BP(...)`.

Comment: This is now edited. Although that is not how my code in IDLE looks so it is not a solution to my problem i'm afraid.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment. If you take your exact code, and then use the stackoverflow markup syntax (indent everything 4 spaces) it will appear in the question exactly as it appears in your file. The end goal is that I should be able to copy and paste what appears in the question and have it work.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a lack of imagination when it comes to naming variables that gave me a hard time. The reason why nothing worked was because of the fact that both player and the button that goes to posion was named "p". Now it is working just fine! Thanks for the help from other users!